# I need to write a loop that makes seven calls to console.log to output the following inverse triangle?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, control-statements

```
#######
######
#####  
####  
###  
##  
#
```

The above question is the problem from the book eloquent javascript. But the question was different as:

Write a loop that makes seven calls to console.log to output the following triangle:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
```

But I need a solution for the exact reverse of this by using the logic below:

```js
for (let line = "#"; line.length < 8; line += "#")
  console.log(line);
```

The below is the code snippet which I tried as above logic  but doesn't work as above:

```js
for (let line = "#######"; line.length > 0; line -= "#")
  console.log(line);
```

Anyone can give me the solution by using the same logic and where I went wrong?

Comment: `line = line.slice(0, -1)` or `line = line.slice(1)` There's no subtraction operator for strings, so you can use string manipulation methods instead.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

```
for (let line = "#######"; line.length > 0; line = line.slice(1))
  console.log(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let test_two = "#";
while (test_two.length <8){
   console.log(test_two);
   test_two +="#";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (let line = '#######'; line.length!=0; line = line.slice(0,line.length -1))
console.log(line);
```

try this